# Method to get number of cores for a executor on a task node?

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing

E.g. I need to get a list of all available executors and their respective multithreading capacity (NOT the total multithreading capacity, sc.defaultParallelism already handle that).

Since this parameter is implementation-dependent (YARN and spark-standalone have different strategy for allocating cores) and situational (it may fluctuate because of dynamic allocation and long-term job running). I cannot use other method to estimate this. Is there a way to retrieve this information using Spark API in a distributed transformation? (E.g. TaskContext, SparkEnv)

**UPDATE** As for Spark 1.6, I have tried the following methods:

1) run a 1-stage job with many partitions ( >> defaultParallelism ) and count the number of distinctive threadIDs for each executorID:

```
val n = sc.defaultParallelism * 16
sc.parallelize(n, n).map(v => SparkEnv.get.executorID -> Thread.currentThread().getID)
.groupByKey()
.mapValue(_.distinct)
.collect()
```

This however leads to an estimation higher than actual multithreading capacity because each Spark executor uses an overprovisioned thread pool.

2) Similar to 1, except that n = defaultParallesim, and in every task I add a delay to prevent resource negotiator from imbalanced sharding (a fast node complete it's task and asks for more before slow nodes can start running):

```
val n = sc.defaultParallelism
sc.parallelize(n, n).map{
  v =>
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    SparkEnv.get.executorID -> Thread.currentThread().getID
}
.groupByKey()
.mapValue(_.distinct)
.collect()
```

it works most of the time, but is much slower than necessary and may be broken by very imbalanced cluster or task speculation.

3) I haven't try this: use java reflection to read BlockManager.numUsableCores, this is obviously not a stable solution, the internal implementation may change at any time.

Please tell me if you have found something better.

Comment: Thank you Paul, this is for scala, I post it late at night so didn't write down my investigation, will add up later

Comment: @Paul updated, is it good enough?

Comment: Looks a lot better than it was.

Comment: You could have a look at `SparkContext.getLocalProperty`, particularly the `spark.executor.cores` property. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: @Adonis, this is the intended cap of the number of cores, not the real one.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy with Spark rest API. You have to get application id:

```
val applicationId = spark.sparkContext.applicationId
```

ui URL:

```
val baseUrl = spark.sparkContext.uiWebUrl
```

and query:

```
val url = baseUrl.map { url => 
  s"${url}/api/v1/applications/${applicationId}/executors"
}
```

With Apache HTTP library (already in Spark dependencies, adapted from https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-rest-client-apache-httpclient-restful-clients):

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import scala.util.Try

val client = new DefaultHttpClient()

val response = url
  .flatMap(url => Try{client.execute(new HttpGet(url))}.toOption)
  .flatMap(response => Try{
    val s = response.getEntity().getContent()
    val json = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(s).getLines.mkString
    s.close
    json
  }.toOption)
```

and json4s:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

case class ExecutorInfo(hostPort: String, totalCores: Int)

val executors: Option[List[ExecutorInfo]] = response.flatMap(json => Try {
  parse(json).extract[List[ExecutorInfo]]
}.toOption)
```

As long as you keep application id and ui URL at hand and open ui port to external connections you can do the same thing from any task.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Let's wait for a few weeks, I feel this can become an anti-pattern if not used carefully, A spark master may manage thousands of nodes and its UI is not designed to be DDoSed by all of them through a not-so-efficient data serialization protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to implement `SparkListener` in a way similar to web UI does. [This code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/exec/ExecutorsTab.scala#L66) might be helpful as an example.

Comment: Good idea! In Spark 1.6 this is the only place where ExecutorInfo is readable, so maybe it worths a try. The only downside is that the listener is only triggered on driver, so its execution is not local.